# How to get login page before going admin page in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to get login page before going admin page in Yii2. For example when I write on browser `http://project/admin/` should redirect me on login page as `http://project/admin/login`.Please anyone help me.

In `Module.php`

```
 public function behaviors(){
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@']
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = '/admin/main/login';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set rules (inside you behavior method) saying which actions are allowed to be accessed when the user is logged or not. In your case, the login action can be accessed when the user is not logged, like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```